# how to know programatically, whether web.xml is reading my spring configuration file or not

Tags: java, spring

i am running simple spring application. i configured web.xml and spring configuration file properly while i am running i am not getting any exceptions but while i am clicking submit button i am getting 404 exception. i understood that my spring configuration file is not reading do that  the controller is not going inside controller class. is there any way to find my spring configuration file is reading or not.

my web.xml file

```
<servlet>
      <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/DispatcherServlet-servlet.xml</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

spring configuration file

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.nic" />
   <!-- <bean name="testclass" class="com.nic.ExampleTest"/> -->

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>
```

jsp file

```
form id="form" action="hello.html" method="post">
User Name:<input type="text" name="uname"/><br/>
<input type="button" value="submit"/>
```

here is my controller class

```
@RequestMapping(value="/hello.html",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String getBean(HttpServletRequest request,ModelMap map) throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException{
    URL resource =  request.getServletContext().getResource("/WEB-INF/spring/DispatcherServlet-servlet.xml");

    InputStream in = resource.openStream();
    DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    docBuilderFactory.setValidating(false);
//  docBuilderFactory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", false);
//  docBuilderFactory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
    DocumentBuilder  dBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(in);

    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("bean");

    for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

        Node nNode = nList.item(temp);


        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

            if(eElement.getElementsByTagName("path")!=null){

                //System.out.println("path : " + eElement.getAttribute("path"));
            }

        }
    }


    return "success";
}
```

Comment: Post your controller. Also you are missing `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in your configuration file.

Comment: check if bean defined in spring's xml are present in applicationContext..

Comment: We will need more information. Whats the path of hello.html in your project ? What is the url of your jsp ? What is the code of your controller ?

Comment: please find my controller class

Answer (score 0):

With what you posted, it looks that Spring just does what you asked it to do.

- you correctly declare a DispatcherServlet in you web.xml, and explicitely give it a xml config file
- the dispatcher servlet is mapped to `/`, meaning that the application should be able to serve directly resources (jsp, css, images) not under WEB-INF
- in the xml config file, you only declare an `InternalResourseViewResolver` - **no controller declaration**

When you hit the submit button, browser posts a request to `/current_path_of_jsp/hello.html`. But as you forgot the `<mvc:annotation-driven />` (as already noted by M. Deinum in comment), the `@RequestMapping` annotation has not been processed by Spring.

BTW : you did not show either whether you controller **class** is annotated with `@Controller`, `@Component`, or `@RequestMapping` ...

Comment: please find my controller class also